# Translating list of inaccurate geo coordinates based on limited accurate geo coordinate data

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations

I have a list of coordinates, about 850 in total.

I need to place them on a map but at the moment, they are slightly off from their proper locations.

I was wondering what the best method to translate (and account for rotation) the points would be.

For example:

```
Accurate:                  Corresponding Inaccurate:

4.545975, -74.481961       4.54602,  -74.482059
4.545592, -74.482415       4.545514, -74.482458
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to verify, are the coordinates in $2$-D space or $3$-D?

Comment: Do we know the cause of why are they inaccurate?

Comment: The coordinates I got originally are in a strange format - gauss kruger. I had to use an obscure program called magna sirgas pro beta 3 to convert them from that format to GPS coordinates. There is an online tool to do it but it doesn't give accurate points on sumapa. The magna sirgas application gives results which look accurate but everything is shifted a few hundred meters away from where we want them.